# Error after installing aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to get paperclip to work with S3 and my views are throwing an error:

```
cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)
```

I have rails configured this way:

Gemfile

```
...
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
...
```

Model

```
user.rb

...
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                         :storage => :s3,
                         :bucket => ENV['lumeo-dev'],
                         :s3_credentials => "lumeot/config/aws.yml",
                         :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
...
```

config/aws.yml

```
development:
  bucket: lumeo-dev
  access_key_id: #
  secret_access_key: #
test:
  bucket: lumeo-test
  access_key_id: #
  secret_access_key: #
production:
  bucket: lumeo-pro
  access_key_id: #
  secret_access_key: #
```

with "#" denoting the correct id/key

Template:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>
  registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
            <div class="inputs">
               <p>
                    <% if current_user.avatar.present? %>
                        Change Photo
                        <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
                    <% else %>
                        Upload New Photo 
                        <%= gravatar_for current_user %>
                    <% end %>
               </p>
               <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
....
```

Please let me know if you see anything incorrect that may help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is now resolved after installing imageMagick: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/README.md

And placing:

```
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

In config/environments/development.rb, which lets paperclip know where to look for imageMagick

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting your server. I had the same error and that worked for me.

Comment: I am facing this issue in the production server. I have rebooted it but no luck. The ruby version is 2.0.0 and rails version is 3.2.17. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you also including the s3 gem?

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```