# Issue with Paperclip/S3 in Rails 3.2.5 "cannot load such file -- aws-sdk"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

Image Uploading was working fine, but when I tried switching it to S3, it started throwing an error. I get the following error when I try to create a new image upload:

```
cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)
```

Relevant gems:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

config/s3.yml:

```
development:
    bucket: bucketname
    access_key_id: #
    secret_access_key: #

test:
    bucket: bucketname
    access_key_id: #
    secret_access_key: #
```

image_upload.rb:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :normal => "1680x6000",
      :result => "560x3000",
      :thumb => "140x500" },
    :path => ":attachment/:style/:normalized_file_name.:extension",
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"
```

Things I have tried:

- bundle install
- Change the version of aws-sdk to 1.3.4
- gem install aws-sdk
- Changed the s3_credentials "Rails.root" part to a few different things.

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369579/error-after-installing-aws-sdk

Comment: The answers there didn't solve my issue, but thank you for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little embarrassing... I just needed to restart rails server. Can't believe I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add `require 'rubygems'` to the top of the file where you are requiring aws-sdk?